# CakePHP 2.x Saving user id from user model into events user_id field in events model from a logged in user

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-model

Hi all I am using Cakephp 2.x. I have an Events model(table) and a users model. When an event is saved I need to save the current logged in users id into the event model's user_id field. The code I have tried has been commented. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

```
public function add(){
        //$this->loadModel('User');
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->Event->create();
            //$this->request->data['Event']['user_id'] = $this->request->data['User']['id'];
            //$this->request->data['Event']['user_id'] = $this->request->data['User']['id'];
            if ($this->Event->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The event has been saved'));
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The event could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
$this->request->data['User']['id'];
```

use

```
$this->Auth->user('id');
```